# Containernized ASP.NET Core apps not working when using Kubernetes Orchestrator

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-container-service, azure-aks

I followed the steps on the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2019

Instead of using Docker Compose, Kubertnes is selected for Container Orchestrator Support for each project.

[image]
However, the project, WebFrontEnd, runs forever (the VS build progress bar is half way) and web app endpoint is not working when it is in debug mode with Azure Dev Spaces.

**Update**

I tried switching to Docker mode when debugging, and switching back to Azure Dev Spaces mode, WebFrontEnd launchs at the url below.

http://localhost:51927/

Should the url not contain "localhost"?

However, the text below is not displayed, which means there is an issue with communication between two containers.

> "Hello from webfrontend and webapi (with value 1)."

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: I cannot, a similar ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124873/helm-install-failed-with-projects-that-has-project-dependency?noredirect=1#comment101152302_57124873