# Helm install failed with projects that has project dependency

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-dev-spaces

I, based on the sample below, created both webfrontend and mywebapi,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/get-started-netcore-visualstudio

and based on the charts folder below from this example, I created similar charts folder for the example above.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/quickstart-team-development
https://github.com/Azure/dev-spaces/tree/master/samples/BikeSharingApp/charts

However, I got errors below when running the script below:

The whole project is available from https://github.com/PingPongSet/AzureDevSpaces

```
az group create --name MyResourceGroup --location eastus
az aks create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyAKS --location eastus --node-vm-size Standard_DS2_v2 --node-count 1 --disable-rbac --generate-ssh-keys
az aks use-dev-spaces -g MyResourceGroup -n MyAKS --space dev --yes
cd C:\_MyLab\AzureCode\DevSpaces\ContainerDependencyWithHelm
azds show-context
cd charts/

PS C:\AzureCode\DevSpaces\ContainerDependencyWithHelm\charts> helm init --wait
$HELM_HOME has been configured at C:\Users\uername\.helm.
Warning: Tiller is already installed in the cluster.
(Use --client-only to suppress this message, or --upgrade to upgrade Tiller to the current version.)

PS C:\AzureCode\DevSpaces\ContainerDependencyWithHelm\charts> helm install -n webfrontendbackend . --dep-up --nam
espace dev --atomic
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'webfrontend'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'mywebapi'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'webfrontend'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'mywebapi'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'webfrontend'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'mywebapi'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'webfrontend'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
2019/07/20 13:18:39 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'mywebapi'. The destination item 'annotations' is a table and ignoring the source 'annotations' as it has a non-table value of: <nil>
INSTALL FAILED
PURGING CHART
Error: release webfrontendbackend failed: Ingress.extensions "mywebapi" is invalid: spec: Invalid value: []extensions.IngressRule(nil): either `backend` or `rules` must be specified
Successfully purged a chart!
Error: release webfrontendbackend failed: Ingress.extensions "mywebapi" is invalid: spec: Invalid value: []extensions.IngressRule(nil): either `backend` or `rules` must be specified
```

Any idea?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Can you tell me about any troubleshooting you have done thus far?

Comment: I added the files under this folder https://github.com/PingPongSet/AzureDevSpaces/tree/master/charts. However, I dont know how to fix it even I tried a few times, because I am new to Helm.